# Xamarin with Visual Studio via Dreamspark

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, dreamspark

Months ago I applied to Xamarin Student program for getting Indie version of Xamarin. However, Dreamspark and Xamarin offers developer studdents to build Xamarin apss with Visual Studio. This wasn't around when we applied. Although it says this on both Dreamspark's site and Xamarin's site. I cannot use Visual Studio still. Is anyone know, why and how to work around this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a licensing question, not a technical one

Comment: This question is off topic for StackOverflow, you probably should email Xamarin directly. That said I believe you can now use [all editions of Xamarin](http://blog.xamarin.com/build-2015-sessions-tests-and-vs-2015/) with Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_student_developer_blog/2016/02/08/learn-xamarin-land-your-dream-job/

Xamarin is available for free for students via dreamspark.com at the following link https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=100